# Indexed data to Parse Server (through MongoDB) doesn't get fetched

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

Since Parse.com's old Dashboard has removed the option to import data from JSON, I'm trying to import the data through MongoDB (my database is not on api.parse.com).

Well, after indexing:

> root@pronuntiadb:~# mongoimport -d 'test' -c 'Palabras' --type json --file /root/parseadas2.json --jsonArray
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:08.003-0400   connected to: localhost
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:11.001-0400   [#.......................] test.Palabras    1.7 MB/21.0 MB (7.9%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:13.999-0400   [###.....................] test.Palabras    3.3 MB/21.0 MB (15.8%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:17.000-0400   [###.....................] test.Palabras    3.3 MB/21.0 MB (15.8%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:20.000-0400   [#####...................] test.Palabras    4.9 MB/21.0 MB (23.5%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:22.999-0400   [#######.................] test.Palabras    6.5 MB/21.0 MB (31.2%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:26.000-0400   [#########...............] test.Palabras    8.3 MB/21.0 MB (39.6%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:28.999-0400   [###########.............] test.Palabras    10.1 MB/21.0 MB (48.1%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:31.999-0400   [#############...........] test.Palabras    11.8 MB/21.0 MB (56.3%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:34.999-0400   [#############...........] test.Palabras    11.8 MB/21.0 MB (56.3%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:38.000-0400   [###############.........] test.Palabras    13.6 MB/21.0 MB (64.6%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:41.003-0400   [#################.......] test.Palabras    15.5 MB/21.0 MB (73.8%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:44.000-0400   [###################.....] test.Palabras    17.3 MB/21.0 MB (82.3%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:47.005-0400   [###################.....] test.Palabras    17.4 MB/21.0 MB (83.0%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:49.999-0400   [#####################...] test.Palabras    19.1 MB/21.0 MB (91.2%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:52.999-0400   [#######################.] test.Palabras    20.8 MB/21.0 MB (99.3%)
>
> 2016-05-26T18:01:55.341-0400   imported 120758 documents

I assigned the same `createdAt` field, which is in the year **2012**, just to difference that pack from the other.

Now, this database is based on **Words** in different languages.

If I filter my data by *Nederlands*, there's no data:

[image]

but if I add one more filter, for example, `createdAt` is lower than the year 2013, it fetches data!!!

[image]

Also I can provide two more screenshots:

A) API Console from Parse:

[image]

B) Count from Mongo (directly on the server)

`>db.Palabras.find({"idioma":"Nederlands"}).count()
20000`

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

Seems like I need to add an extra filter (date lower than) for the words I imported through Mongo, but not for the rest.

I also realised that if I filter with `createdAt` lower than year 2016, I don't get any information!!! but if I filter by `createdAt` lower than 2013, I get it!!

[image]